# JavaScript Find Specific URLs.

Tags: javascript, url, window.location

Alright, I've been working on a userscript that redirects when a specific page is loaded.

This is what I have so far:

```
function blockThreadAccess() {
    var TopicLink = "http://www.ex.com/Forum/Post.aspx?ID=";
    var Topics = [ '57704768', '53496466', '65184688', '41182608', '54037954', '53952944', '8752587', '47171796', '59564382', '59564546', '2247451', '9772680', '5118578', '529641', '63028895', '22916333', '521121', '54646501', '36320226', '54337031' ];
    for(var i = 0; i < Topics.length; i++) {
        if(window.location.href == TopicLink + Topics[i]) {
            // Execute Code
        }
    }
}
```

The function is called on the page load, but it doesn't seem execute the code.

What it's supposed to do is check to see if the user is on that specific page, and if he is then execute the code.

Say someone goes to this link - http://www.ex.com/Forum/Post.aspx?ID=54646501, it then redirects the use. I'm trying to make it efficient so I don't have to add a bunch of if statements.

Comment: What is the problem with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try converting both to lower case before comparing

```
var loc = window.location.href.toLowerCase();
var topicLnk = TopicLink.toLowerCase();
for(var i = 0; i < Topics.length; i++) {
    if(topicLnk + Topics[i] == loc) {
        // Execute Code
    }
}
```